# for loop with function that also sleeps after nrows [R]

Tags: r, for-loop, rtweet

I am using `rtweet` to `lookup_users` for a very large number of accounts (>900,000). This function returns up to 90,000 users and then there is a rate limit, which only resets after 15 minutes. How do I build a for loop that iterates over the first 90,000 values in a vector (or dataframe) and then waits 15 minutes, then iterates over the next 90,000, etc., respecting the rate limit?

Comment: perhaps `Sys.sleep(15 * 60 / 90000)` at the end of the loop?  Effectively a 0.01 second pause at each iteration ensures you don't ever exceed the limit.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Sys.sleep()`:

```
i <- 1

while (i < n_accounts) {

do_something()
Sys.sleep(900)
i <- i + 90000

}
```